# Visual Flow to edit multiple lines

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow

We are currently having issues with the standard Salesforce data entry of OrderProducts (`OrderItem`). We have a Screen Flow that is used to populate 10-200 line items at a time with shared values, but then users must edit each line item to provide Serial Numbers and other line specific details.

The issue is two-fold. One, there is a bug that is causing the field when converting from static to editable after several edits it freezes and locks the screen up, often causing lost work when attempting to save, as well as lost time with a hard refresh. Salesforce has been notified but is having difficulty reproducing the issue to do anything about it. Not to mention that even if they figure it out I believe the soonest they could implement a fix would be the next release. :/

Secondly, apart from major issue, there is a major annoyance with the lighting functionality when doing 10-key data entry. Every tab/arrow to the next field causes JS to convert the field type to be editable and that creates a lag that makes it difficult for our team to maintain the pace of data entry that we require.

Therefore, we need to create a solution as quickly as possible to overcome these major concerns of the business. It is my goal to use clicks before code as much as possible, but before I dive too deeply into an issue that could have been avoided I wanted to post this for possible solutions.

**Current Solutions in Mind**

1) Create a Visual Flow that uses a custom lighting component that can receive a list of OrderProducts and provide a similar interface with basic text fields and picklist

- Can this be done?

2) Create a complete custom visualforce component

Answer (score 0):

1) Probably. Lightning components will be tricky at first glance, since list of objects [isn't currently available](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_tips_map.htm) for a lightning component implementing `lightning:availableForFlowScreens`. 
Maybe generating the OrderLineItems via component's apex controller would do the trick. Pass in OrderId, let cmp and apex create items, do a reload in flow.

2) Surely. You have all options from JS Remoting to good, plain Apex + VF.